# How to create functions in PHP

Tags: php, function, session

I'm new to PHP and I've created a PHP session script that times-out after 30 minutes of inactivity and it works fine.

However, I would like to put it in a function and call it in pages that would require it in order to avoid DRY. How can I achieve this?

PS: The function I created throws 'Undefined index' error.
Snippet of the code is below:

```
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();
    if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION[$'LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 5)) {
        // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: index.php');
          // exit;              
    }
```

Comment: Check the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php).

Comment: I already have, but it's not working. I've searched the net as well

Comment: Then please show your function code. What you posted is not a function, we can't help you if you don't share it.

Comment: You also have a typo here: `$_SESSION[$'LAST_ACTIVITY']` should be `$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']`. And you should assign it (`$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();`) at the end, not at the beginning, otherwise your condition will always evaluate to false.

Answer (score 0):

```
function callMe() {
    $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();
    if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 5)) { 
        // you should not use $ with array indexes/keys

        // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: index.php');
          // exit;              
    }
}
```

> PS: The function I created throws 'Undefined index' error. The snippet of the code is below:

In your given snippet a function is nowhere visible, it's just procedural code with a condition block.

**By the way, you should use the search engine first.**

Here's the link to user-defined functions documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: I've been able to fix it. Thanks

Comment: @jessebrite you got an option of the accepted answer. If it really solved your problem do mark this answer as an accepted answer.